# Issue running playwright-python in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, playwright

my project is using playwright-python and my team has been unable to run playwright in a docker container. We are able to build the docker image successfully, but problems arise when the image is running. May I obtain some guidance on how to tackle this issue?

We are using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal, so it is not a version issue.

Here is the configuration of our Dockerfile.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8

#ENV PATH=.\env\Scripts\Activate.ps1

WORKDIR /code



#RUN which python3

COPY ./requirement.txt /code/requirement.txt
#RUN set -xe \
#    && apt-get update -y \
#    && apt-get install - y python3-pip
#RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt
RUN set -xe
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get update
#RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get install -y python3 pip
#RUN python3 --version

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirement.txt

COPY ./ /code/server
RUN playwright install
RUN playwright install-deps
RUN ls -al
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /code/server/env/bin/activate && pip3 install --upgrade -r /code/requirement.txt"]

CMD ["python3", "-m", "uvicorn", "server.main:app", "--port", "9900", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Here is the error we are getting:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Host system is missing a few dependencies to run browsers. ║
║ Please install them with the following command:            ║
║                                                            ║
║     playwright install-deps                                ║
║                                                            ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                         ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 226, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 159, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/Project-Scrapee/./server/multiproxy/route.py", line 35, in refresh_proxy_list
    await crud.refresh_proxy_list()
  File "/Project-Scrapee/./server/multiproxy/crud.py", line 65, in refresh_proxy_list
    await scheduler_crud.refresh_proxy()
  File "/Project-Scrapee/./server/scheduler.py", line 640, in refresh_proxy
    await multiproxy_crud.scrape_proxies()
  File "/Project-Scrapee/./server/multiproxy/crud.py", line 77, in scrape_proxies
    page = await page_gen.anext()
  File "/Project-Scrapee/./server/template/crud.py", line 785, in get_pw_page
    browser = await p.chromium.launch(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/async_api/_generated.py", line 11602, in launch
    await self._async(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_async_base.py", line 68, in _async
    setattr(task, "pw_stack_trace", traceback.extract_stack())
```

We have tried many ways to install playwright but we can't get to install playwright in the image.

Answer (score 1):

I was NOT able to install Playwright dependencies starting from a Python base image (ie `FROM python:3.9`), the only way to get it working was to use an Ubuntu base image which is supported OS by Playwright, then install Python and the rest (application dependencies and Playwright)

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3.9
RUN apt install -y python3-pip

COPY app/ /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN playwright install --with-deps chromium

CMD ....
```

Comment: That is interesting, I have not considered that. One of the problems that we encountered was the version of playwright installed was somehow different from the one that we were supposed to install because the playwright version specified in the dockerfile was different from the version stated in requirements.txt. I'm not sure if libxtst6 was missing like the other person suggested but I installed it too.

Answer (score 0):

This was an existing issue that was fixed in some earlier release. It shouldn't be happening now. As suggested in this [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/12613), can you try installing `libxtst6` using this command `RUN apt-get install -y python3 pip && apt install libxtst6` and then try with the docker image

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. My team hasn't been able to work on the project for a while. I tried installing libxtst6, although we had a playwright version issue too. Thanks for the help!